# outline around glass shader without turning everything black?

Tags: shaders, toon-shading

Im trying to get an outline around this glass shader but it keeps occluding the top part of the glass that should be transparent. Is there any way around this? The outline is done with a solidify modifer on a negative value > flip normals > material offset set to 1 (I only have two materials on this specific object > backface culling checked on outline material. A glass shader and the black outline material).

If there's a better method to getting outlines without freestyle mode Id be happy to learn. Ive found this just gives me the best results while still allowing me to adjust things on the fly in the viewport. I always have problems with freestyle mode and i hate having to render every time just to see what needs adjusting.

[image]

Comment: The black area is the so-called inverted hull that creates the black outline. Here it's visible because the glass in front of it is transparent. I'm not sure if you can get rid of it and keep the outline at the same time.

Comment: Yes I was just trying to find a way around it, But there doesn't seem to be anything.